# Jackson JSON to pojo from array of objects with no property name

Tags: java, jackson

Considering this structure, what is the correct notation for getting the array of objects (property, type fields) inside of the parent property.

```
{"parent":
          [
            {"property":[2,5],"type":2},
            {"property":[1,2],"type":1},
            {"property":[4,0],"type":0}
          ],
 "prop2":"something"
}
```

Currently the java looks like

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Parent{
       <WHAT TO PUT HERE??>
       List<PropertyTypeObj> propertyTypes;
    }
```

This is part of something larger like:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Container{

        @JsonProperty("parent")
        List<Parent> parent;
        @JsonProperty("prop2")
        String prop2
    }
```

The solution was to bypass the parent element creation and instead use the **PropertyTypeObject** itself

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
        public class Container{

            @JsonProperty("parent")
            List<PropertyTypeObject> properties;
            @JsonProperty("prop2")
            String prop2
        }
```

And then specify the PropertyTypeObject as having `@JsonRootName("parent")`

See approved answer for clarity.

Comment: You may want to rethink your parent class - Parent wont have a list of PropertyTypeObjects but rather a list of objects that contain a property and a type

Comment: I figured it out, it is in line with the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible class structure is the following:

```
public class External {
   private List<External.Internal> parent;
   private String prop2; 

   @JsonRootName("parent")
   public static class Internal {
     private List<Integer> property;
     private Integer type;
   }
}
```

where the external class has:

- a **parent** property that is a List (array in the json) of Inner elements
- **prop2** property of type String

and an internal class that has for each element:

- a **property** property of type List (array in json) of integers
- a **type** property of type integer

Comment: correct, I will edit yor answer with the correct solution.